# Laravel 5.1: After logging out and redirecting to login page the Auth::user() still exists

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, oauth-2.0

Running Laravel 5.1.45 (LTS) and [lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel). Log the user out using `Auth::logout()` and redirect them to `'/'`. At this point I would expect `Auth::check()` to return false and `Auth::user()` to be null but the check yields true the user object still exists. Users currently log in with the password grant.

**Login**

```
public function access_token() {
    return Response::json(Authorizer::issueAccessToken());
}
```

**Logout**

```
Route::get('/logout', function() {
    Auth::logout();
    Session::clear();
    return Redirect::to('/');
});
```

**/ Route**

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    $user = Auth::user(); // Still exists after logging out
    return view('root')->with('user', $user);
});
```

I've tried using Laravel's built-in `AuthController@logout` which yields the same problem. My access tokens live for 1 hour.

How do I ensure that the user still isn't logged in after they've logged out?